# How to run @property getter conditionally, e.g. for filtration purposes

Tags: python, decorator

I have a list of dictionaries for a property of a class, which is implemented with @property getter and setter. Yet I would like to have a conditional getter or an alternative implementation with the same name.

I've my class and @property with getter and setter running and unit-tested. The only thing missing is a pythonic implementation of a conditional getter for filtration purposes.

I have looked at the official documentation, googled, very briefly looked at some Pandas source code.

```
# python v3.7.2
# simplified code

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self)
    self.uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())
    self.my_dict = []

@property
def mydict(self)
    return self._mydict

@mydict.setter
def mydict(self, inputdict)
    self._mydict.append({
        'target': inputdict.get('target').uuid})
```

> A, B, C = MyClass()
>
> A.mydict = {'target': B}
>
> print(A.mydict)

[{'target': B.uuid}]

> A.mydict = {'target': C}
>
> print(A.mydict)

[{'target': B.uuid}, {'target': C.uuid}]

And I want to have

> print(A.mydict(target=B))

[{'target': B.uuid}]

which would require extra coding to process supposed keyword arguments within getter, yet

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: You can't have a property (like `A.mydict`) and a method (like `A.mydict(target=B)`) with the same name. You can see how that's awfully ambiguous, right? Not a thing you want to do, really.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not see a problem here, because `A.mydict` is not a property, it is a method under `@property` decorator; moreover, getters are things that return somehow pre-processed data, and filtering fits this logic rather well.

From the syntaxis standpoint, I see the problem, one being a property, and another being a method; but `@property` might cover it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by the commentators, and because of the intentional difference between properties and methods, and because of the thing I am working on has both data and behavior, I created a specialized class for this thing.

I post both the class and unit tests for the behavior. Most likely, this code is prone to bugs, but it does the job for the current version of the pet project. Any tips and potential problems with the usability and scaling are welcome.

```
class Correspondence(dict):
"""A class for Correspondence data structure, see Chapter 2 of the book."""

def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """Update the correspondence object with the unique keys."""
    try:
        keyid = args[0]['target'] + args[0]['source'] + args[0]['condition']
        self[keyid] = args[0]
    except KeyError:
        raise TypeError('The input should contain source, target, \
            condition and truthvalue as keys of the input dictionary')

def filter(self, source=None, target=None, condition=None, truthvalue=None):
    """Filter Correspondence object. (target ⇐ source))

    Input:
        source:     filtering condition, source
        target:     filtering condition, target
        condition:  filtering conidtion, correspondence condition
        truthvalue: filtering condition, truthvalue excluding 
    Output:
        output: a Correspondence instance
    """

    filters = {
        'source': source,
        'target': target,
        'condition': condition,
        'truthvalue': truthvalue}
    filters = {k: v for k, v in filters.items() if v is not None}


    if not bool(filters):
        return self
    else:
        _correspondence = copy.deepcopy(self)
        # iterate over filters, followed by iteration over items
        # if the conditions are not satisfied, then items are removed
        # matrix-based computation would be more efficient,
        # but would do for now unless performance issues
        for filter_key, filter_value in filters.items():
            for key, value in self.items():
                if value[filter_key] is not filter_value:
                    del _correspondence[key]

        return _correspondence
```

The unit tests

```
def test_correspondence_structure_and_methods(self):
    # check if correspondence has the right structure
    BA_correspondence = {
        'source': 'A.uuid',
        'target': 'B.uuid',
        'condition': 'the condition',
        'truthvalue': 'true'}

    CA_correspondence = {
        'source': 'A.uuid',
        'target': 'C.uuid',
        'condition': 'the condition',
        'truthvalue': 'true'}

    CA_correspondence_wrong = {
        'sources': 'A.uuid',          # the key should be "source"
        'target': 'C.uuid',
        'condition': 'the condition',
        'truthvalue': 'true'}

    BA_correspondence_upd = {
        'source': 'A.uuid',
        'target': 'B.uuid',
        'condition': 'the condition',
        'truthvalue': 'unverifiable'}

    correspondence = fabric.Correspondence()

    # test if Correspondence.update() processes the right data
    self.assertRaises(
        TypeError,
        correspondence.update,
        CA_correspondence_wrong)

    correspondence.update(BA_correspondence)
    # (B ⇐ A)
    self.assertDictEqual(
        {'B.uuidA.uuidthe condition': BA_correspondence},
        correspondence)

    # (B ⇐ A) ⋅ (C ⇐ A)
    correspondence.update(CA_correspondence)
    self.assertDictEqual(
        {
            'B.uuidA.uuidthe condition': BA_correspondence,
            'C.uuidA.uuidthe condition': CA_correspondence},
        correspondence)

    # updated truthvalue with the same source, target, and condition
    # (B ⇐ A) ⋅ (C ⇐ A)
    correspondence.update(BA_correspondence_upd)
    self.assertDictEqual(
        {
            'B.uuidA.uuidthe condition': BA_correspondence_upd,
            'C.uuidA.uuidthe condition': CA_correspondence},
        correspondence)

    # filter correspondence
    self.assertDictEqual(
        {
            'B.uuidA.uuidthe condition': BA_correspondence_upd,
            'C.uuidA.uuidthe condition': CA_correspondence},
        correspondence.filter())

    self.assertDictEqual(
        {
            'B.uuidA.uuidthe condition': BA_correspondence_upd},
        correspondence.filter(target='B.uuid'))

    self.assertDictEqual(
        {
            'B.uuidA.uuidthe condition': BA_correspondence_upd,
            'C.uuidA.uuidthe condition': CA_correspondence},
        correspondence.filter(source='A.uuid'))

    self.assertDictEqual(
        {
            'B.uuidA.uuidthe condition': BA_correspondence_upd,
            'C.uuidA.uuidthe condition': CA_correspondence},
        correspondence.filter(condition='the condition'))

    self.assertDictEqual(
        {
            'C.uuidA.uuidthe condition': CA_correspondence},
        correspondence.filter(truthvalue='true'))

    self.assertDictEqual(
        {
            'B.uuidA.uuidthe condition': BA_correspondence_upd},
        correspondence.filter(source='A.uuid', truthvalue='unverifiable'))

    self.assertDictEqual(
        {
            'B.uuidA.uuidthe condition': BA_correspondence_upd},
        correspondence.
            filter(source='A.uuid').filter(truthvalue='unverifiable'))
```